# How to fix verbal deployment errors with react project?

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I am trying to deploy a react personal portfolio using Vercel, but keep getting these errors. How do i fix? I also don't understand the error about img because it is in src [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4l2S.jpg)

code to my portfolio: https://github.com/Kdot117/Personal-portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines in your code in `Work.js` are the issue.
You are importing images with absolute paths.

```
import BusinessCard from "/Users/kendrickizaguirre_1/kendricks-portfolio/src/BusinessCard.jpg"
import pizza from "/Users/kendrickizaguirre_1/kendricks-portfolio/src/components/pizza.jpg"
import madstat2 from "/Users/kendrickizaguirre_1/kendricks-portfolio/src/components/madstat2.jpg”
```

A cleaner approach (without using a library) will be to.

1. Make an `images` folder inside `src`.
2. Copy all images you are importing in js components inside this folder.  or with meaningful subfolders inside the `image` folder.
3. Finally import the images in the components with the relative path.

So if I change your package structure as below.

```
└── Personal-portfolio
    ├── README.md
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── manifest.json
    └── src
        ├── App.css
        ├── App.js
        ├── components
        │   ├── About.js
        │   ├── Contact.js
        │   ├── Header.js
        │   ├── Navigation.js
        │   └── Work.js
        ├── images
        │   ├── BusinessCard.jpg
        │   ├── abstract.jpg
        │   ├── kenny.jpg
        │   ├── madstat.jpg
        │   ├── madstat2.jpg
        │   └── pizza.jpg
        ├── index.css
        └── index.js
```

Then import in `Work.js` will look like this

```
import BusinessCard from “../images/BusinessCard.jpg"
import pizza from "../images/pizza.jpg"
import madstat2 from "../images/madstat2.jpg”
```

Comment: @Kendrick I sent you a PR on GitHub. 
I’m able to run it after the changes. I had to update Header.js and App.css too

Answer (score 0):

You are importing some files from an absolute path pointing to your laptop a as you can see here:
https://github.com/Kdot117/Personal-portfolio/search?q=%2Fusers%2F

Replace those with relative imports, such that

`/Users/kendrickizaguirre_1/kendricks-portfolio/src/components/BusinessCard.jpg` becomes `src/components/BusinessCard.jpg`, which will then be available also in Vercel.

BUT. Here's a better alternative. Move those images to a folder called `public`. And then Next.js will serve those as static files as explained here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

In this case you don't need to import anything, you would simply say `<img src="/BusinessCard.jpg">`

Additionally, you might want to take a look at Next Image component for optimized images out-of-the-box: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization